# Eclipseによるプロキシを経由したリモートデバッグは可能ですか？

Tags: java, eclipse

Weblogicサーバにて実行中のプロセスに対して、別のPC上のEclipseからプロキシ経由でアタッチしてリモートデバッグを行うことは可能でしょうか。

環境は次の通りです。
サーバ コンテナ Weblogic 12c
クライアント(IDE) Eclipse Neon.2 Release 4.6.2
サーバクライアント共に Java 1.8.0_231

サーバ側の起動オプションには以下を指定しています。

```
java -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8453,server=y,suspend=n (...以下略)
```

Eclipse側では、まず「ウィンドウ」→「設定」→「一般」→「ネットワーク接続」で「アクティブ・プロバイダー」を「マニュアル」に設定して「HTTP」「HTTPS」「SOCKS」それぞれにプロキシのホストとポートを設定した状態で、「実行」→「デバッグの構成」→「リモート Java アプリケーション」にて、プロジェクトにデバッグ対象のプロジェクトを選択、ホストにWeblogicが実行されているサーバのIPアドレス、ポートに 8453 を指定しています。

この状態でデバッグを開始すると、数秒後に「リモート VM に接続できませんでした。接続がタイムアウトしました。 org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException」というエラーになります。

サーバ側で netstat したところ、ポート 8453 は LISTEN 状態だったので、サーバ側の設定は問題ないと考えているのですが、Eclipse側の「ネットワーク接続」の設定を「ダイレクト」にしたり「ネイティブ」にしたりといろいろ変えても現象が変わらないので、そもそもこの「ネットワーク接続」の設定はリモートデバッグに関係していないようにも感じます。

また、「デバッグの構成」の設定にもプロキシに関する設定がなく、Eclipseはおそらくデバッガにjdbを使用しているのだと思いますが、jdbのオプションにプロキシに関するものがないようで、もしかするとプロキシを経由したリモートデバッグは不可能なのではないかと思えてきました。

ということで、冒頭の質問となります。そもそもプロキシ経由でリモートデバッグができるのでしょうか。もし可能であるなら、その方法を教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: プロキシを使う場合は、プロキシサーバーが必要だと思いますがたてられていますか？この場合 HTTP/HTTPSのプロキシはプロトコルが違うので使えないので、SOCKSプロキシになると思うけれど、デバッガが使ってくれるのかどうか・・・Java自体は対応してるようですが。

Comment: プロキシサーバはあります。おっしゃる通り、Eclipseの「ネットワーク接続」の設定はリモートデバッグに対しては効いていない気がしています。HTTPプロキシはダメそうでした。プロキシにNATを入れるなどして通信を転送するしかないのかなという気がしています。

Answer (score 0):

Eclipseでデバッグ起動→同一PCにFiddler（プロキシサーバー）インストール→他PCでテストなら実施したことがありますが、やりたいことと合ってますでしょうか。

Fiddlerの使い方はiPhoneでテストする方法が記載しているページがあるので、同じことをPCでやればよいです。

[fiddlerでiPhoneの通信を見るためにやったことメモ](https://qiita.com/dolls/items/6ad469c271f88a95a6f9)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。まず、PCから対象のサーバへは直接接続することができず、必ずプロキシサーバ経由での接続となる環境で、teratermなど他のソフトではプロキシの設定をしてそのサーバへ接続しています。Eclipseの場合も同様の設定があるのか、そもそも不可能なのかというのが質問の主旨となります。